# how to set directory permissions of windows server 2012 so Visual Basic 2015 windows app ‘kill’ doesn’t get file permission error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, permissions

I have a Visual-Basic windows app that reads incoming SMTP email files from `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\` and then moves them renamed to `C:\primary\`

I’ve set Windows file permissions of both directories `C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\` and `C:\primary\` to “everyone” full access.

I have a 2nd VB.NET Windows app that reads each file, processes it, then deletes it using `kill(filepath)` which gets the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Access to the path '\\<my server>\C\Primary\9255551212@vzwpix.com #71615 1.TXT' is denied.”
```

The files security permissions has “everyone” full access.

How do I set file permissions for the directories to prevent this error and be safe from hacker attack and not use “everyone” permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:   Changed \\C  to just "C:".